# How to share one state with 3 different components?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I got 3 components balance, buyStock and sellStock that need to share availableFunds state with $100,000 initial value. When I click buy stock button in buyStock component, money value in availableFunds get reduced so balance and sellStock components need to know updated availableFunds state simultaneously. And when I sell stock in sellStock component, vice versa. Currently, balance component resides above both buyStock and sellStock component. I tried to solve this problem using redux toolkit, but having trouble coming up with proper design. I haven't learnt context API yet, but is context API more effective solution in this case?

Comment: State is available to all connected components--it's not clear what you mean by "the state is above" if you're using Redux without explicit context. If you're not, and the state is already "above" the components in question, then if that state is passed as props, you're already done. You'll likely need to provide more details.

Comment: It can be confusing how to handle state. In the beginning it is useful to ignore solutions like redux or context API. Get a good understanding how state works if you put it in App and hand it down as prop. After you are comfortable with that you still have time to learn redux and context.

Answer (score 4):

Just put the state in a component above all of them. And distribute it as prop.

```
const App = () => {
    const [availableFunds, setAvailableFunds] = useState(100000)
    return <>
        <Balance availableFunds={availableFunds} />

        <BuyStock availableFunds={availableFunds}
            setAvailableFunds={setAvailableFunds} />

        <SellStock availableFunds={availableFunds}
            setAvailableFunds={setAvailableFunds} />
    </>
}
```

then you can use it freely inside your 3 components.

```
const Balance = ({ availableFunds }) => <div>Balance: ${availableFunds}</div>

const BuyStock = ({ availableFunds, setAvailableFunds }) =>
    <button
        onClick={() => setAvailableFunds(availableFunds - 10000)}
        disabled={availableFunds < 10000}
    >
        Buy
    </button>

const SellStock = ({ availableFunds, setAvailableFunds }) =>
    <button
        onClick={() => setAvailableFunds(availableFunds + 10000) }
    >
        Sell
    </button>
```

It is easier to start this way and get used to react. After that you can try redux or context API

Comment: Cool this worked! I never seen setState in this case setAvailableFunds getting passed down as props ever. What does passing both availableFunds and setAvailableFunds as props do here? I appreciate the help.

Comment: Passing availableFunds and setAvailableFunds just makes them available inside the component (i.e. BuyStock). You can use them just as if you got them from useState(). But now all components will show changes to state.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use connect() function to connect each of your components to the part of the state you need the component to have access to:

https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect